# Setting up AUCTeX: LaTeX-mode-hook does not work

Tags: emacs, lambda, auctex

I have a strange problem. When I set up my AUCTeX configuration for Latex like this

```
(require 'tex)
(TeX-global-PDF-mode t)
```

it works for me.

But when I alter the code by putting in a `lambda` function

```
(add-hook LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
    (require 'tex)
    (TeX-global-PDF-mode t)
))
```

it won't work.

Could someone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a `'` to the immediate left of `LaTeX-mode-hook`.  Also, you need to `(require 'tex)` **before** using the `LaTeX-mode-hook`.

Because the library AUCTeX defines the variable `LaTeX-mode-hook` (i.e., brings it into existence), placing `(require 'tex)` inside a hook that does not yet exist will not work.  [See line 5017 of `~/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.87.3/latex.el`)

```
(require 'tex)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (TeX-global-PDF-mode t)
  ))
```

---

Normally, I see this used:  `(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)`.  However, the original poster is correct regarding the existence of a function named `TeX-global-PDF-mode` -- see line 1729 of `~/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.87.3/tex.el`.

---

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/foo_tex.png))</sub>

Comment: Oh,my Emacs still does not work upon your suggestion.

Comment: I just verified that it works.  If you create a file called `foo.tex` and (from that new buffer, i.e., `foo.tex`) use `M-x describe-variable RET TeX-PDF-mode RET`, you will see that the value is `t`.  You have to load a `*.tex` file for the `LaTeX-mode-hook` to be triggered.

Comment: Make sure you have `(require 'package) (package-initialize)` **near the very beginning** of your `.emacs` file -- **before** any settings relating to the various package installations. I used `M-x list-packages` to perform the installation and the version is `auctex-11.87.3`.

Comment: When troubleshooting, often times the most helpful method will be to eliminate all potential conflicts -- e.g., by using a virtually blank / empty `.emacs` file with just the bare minimum configuration.  In this case, the bare minimum configuration is `(require 'package) (package-initialize)` followed by the code in my answer.  If it doesn't work correctly at that point, then there is something wrong with the installation of either Emacs or AUCTeX.  In that case, back-up your stuff and start again.

Comment: Thank you,I revised the bug in my program. Your information make my faster to solve the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Delete following line if you have in your "init.el".

```
(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)
```

Although the line is suggested in"auctex-reademe.txt", I think
following is more appropriate.

```
(load "preview" nil t t)
```